# Restrict Bootstrap Navbar to one row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to restrict the bootstrap navbar to one row in [this code](http://codepen.io/bigbanner/pen/KwROYN). When the screen resizes (specifically at 1465px) the bootstrap navbar extends itself into two rows. To limit the navbar to one row I'd like to make the btn-group smaller as the screen width shrinks. How could I dynamically change the size of the message-button-group shown below?

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a href="/Message" class="btn btn-default pull-left truncate-message" id="message-button-group">
        <span class="badge pull-left" style="margin-right: 10px;">5</span> Subject5: Message4
      </a>
      <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:40px" id="dropdown-button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu truncate-message" role="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="/Message">Subject4: Message3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/Message">Subject3: Message2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/Message">Subject2: Message1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/Message">Subject1: Message0</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Simply removing the `1000px` width on the button group goes a long way. Are you trying to keep that at maximum width?

Comment: @isherwood yes I'd like to keep a static btn-group size if possible. The messages I will be diplaying in real time will have different lengths, which means a constantly resizing btn-group. I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One idea (Bootstrap 3) is to create four classes with different widths and take advantage of Bootstrap's visible responsive classes:

```
  <a href="/Message" class="btn btn-default pull-left truncate-message width-1 visible-xs" id="message-button-group">
    <span class="badge pull-left" style="margin-right: 10px;">5</span> Subject5: Message4
  </a>

  <a href="/Message" class="btn btn-default pull-left truncate-message width-2 visible-sm" id="message-button-group">
    <span class="badge pull-left" style="margin-right: 10px;">5</span> Subject5: Message4
  </a>

  <a href="/Message" class="btn btn-default pull-left truncate-message width-3 visible-md" id="message-button-group">
    <span class="badge pull-left" style="margin-right: 10px;">5</span> Subject5: Message4
  </a>

  <a href="/Message" class="btn btn-default pull-left truncate-message width-4 visible-lg" id="message-button-group">
    <span class="badge pull-left" style="margin-right: 10px;">5</span> Subject5: Message4
  </a>
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you for your answer @dwkd. I've updated the codepen [here](http://codepen.io/bigbanner/pen/KwROYN). I did what you said and then took away the css formatting on the xs visibility to allow for dynamic resizing on the button dropdown. Thanks again.